# Argument variables in a shell script

Tags: sh

I would like some tips about this problem :

I'd like to run a script bash, this one call suiviTest2 so I launch ./suiviTest2 :

```
#!/bin/sh

echo $1
echo"-----------------------------------"
set CLASSPATH=""
echo"-----------------------------------"

echo $1

for jar in lib/*.jar; do CLASSPATH="$jar;${CLASSPATH}"; done

echo using classpath $CLASSPATH

/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/java -classpath ${CLASSPATH} suivi.test.TestSuivi                        
conf/suivi.properties $1

echo $1
```

but It gave me :

```
$ ./suiviTest2 CHRP
CHRP
./suiviTest2: line 4: echo----------------------------------- : command not found
./suiviTest2: line 6: echo----------------------------------- : command not found
CLASSPATH=
using classpath lib/xmlsec-1.4.3.jar;lib/wss4j-1.5.9.jar;lib/velosurf-2.3-r526.jar;lib/velocity-> > 1.6-dev.jar;lib/suivi.jar;lib/stillness-0.1-dev.jar;lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar;lib/mail-1.4.jar;lib/jdom-1.1.jar;lib/dom4j-1.1.jar;lib/commons-net-3.1.jar;lib/commons-logging-1.1.jar;lib/commons-lang-2.2.jar;lib/commons-discovery-0.2.jar;lib/commons-collections-3.2.jar;lib/axis-jaxrpc-1.4.jar;lib/axis-1.4.jar;C:\PROJECTS_BOXTALE\boxtale\suivi\classes\suivi\test
ola
conf/suivi.properties
CLASSPATH=
CLASSPATH=
```

Have you got any ideas? any tips?
If you need some more informations, please tell me?

Comment: you could decribe more claerly what is wrong and translate whatever the language is (Spanish ?) to English

Comment: To get English message, add `LANG=C` before your command.

Comment: "commande introuvable" means "command not found" in French, in case anyone is wondering (credit to Google Translate).

Comment: This script is not `bash`. It's `sh`. Take a look at the invocation *shebang*.

Comment: The `set` command allows you to assign the positional parameters ($1, $2, ..., $@, $#, $*). If you just want to assign a shell variable, omit "set"

Answer (score 2):

You need to add one or more space after `echo` to split command and arguments:

```
echo "-----------------------------------"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot kamae, I solve the problem :  just put CLASSPATH="" instead set CLASSPATH="" in the beginning of the script alligato